# Resolver Not Receiving Arguments when Nested

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have a list of classes stored in memory that I am trying to parse through various types. It is referenced through the method `get_inventory()`.

When I call the classes individually, they resolve as I would expect.

But when I try to nest one in the other, the value is returning null.

The code, followed by some examples:

```
class Account(graphene.ObjectType):

    account_name = graphene.String()
    account_id = graphene.String()

    def resolve_account(
        self, info,
        account_id=None,
        account_name=None
    ):

        inventory = get_inventory()

        result = [Account(
            account_id=i.account_id,
            account_name=i.account_name
        ) for i in inventory if (
            (i.account_id == account_id) or 
            (i.account_name == account_name)
        )]

        if len(result):
            return result[0]
        else:
            return Account()

account = graphene.Field(
    Account, 
    resolver=Account.resolve_account, 
    account_name=graphene.String(default_value=None),
    account_id=graphene.String(default_value=None)
)

class Item(graphene.ObjectType):

    item_name = graphene.String()
    region = graphene.String()
    account = account

    def resolve_item(
        self, info,
        item_name=None
    ):
        inventory = get_inventory()

        result = [Item(
            item_name=i.item_name,
            region=i.region,
            account=Account(
                account_id=i.account_id
            )
        ) for i in inventory if (
            (i.item_name == item_name)
        )]

        if len(result):
            return result[0]
        else:
            return Item()

item = graphene.Field(
    Item, 
    resolver=Item.resolve_item, 
    item_name=graphene.String(default_value=None)
)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    account = account
    item = item

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

Let's assume I have an account `foo` that has an item `bar`. The below queries return the fields correctly.

```
{
  account(accountName:"foo") {
    accountName
    accountId
  }
}

{
  item(itemName: "bar") {
    itemName
    region
  }
}
```

So if I wanted to find the account that has the item `bar`, I would think I could query `bar` and get `foo`. But it returns the `account` fields as `null`.

```
{
  item(itemName: "bar") {
    itemName
    region
    account {
      accountId
      accountName
    }
  }
}
```

Recall that as part of `resolve_item`, I am doing `account=Account(account_id=i.account_id)` - I would expect this to work.

If I alter the last return statement of `resolve_account` to the below, `accountId` always returns `yo`.

```
...
else:
    return Account(
        account_id='yo'
    )
```

So this tells me that my resolver is firing, but the invocation in `resolve_item` is not passing `account_id` properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am seeing, it looks like rather than being passed in as an argument, `account_id` is being stored already as part of `account` in the `ObjectType`.

So if I add the below, I can get to the result that I want.

`account_id = account_id if getattr(self, "account", None) is None else self.account.account_id`

Answer (score 2):

This is because the arguments on a field are only available to its immediate children. If you need to retrieve the argument in nested elements, your top level resolver needs to return the argument as part of the source and your nested element can access it arguments now from the source object.

Comment: Not sure I exactly follow - shouldn't it also accept `kwargs` passed in when invoked?